# How do I only serve the HSTS header on https:// and not on http:// requests

Tags: iis-10, hsts

I am implementing HSTS. The check on https://hstspreload.org/ tells me that it's all good but I serve the HSTS header over HTTP which is unnecessary.

**Warning: Unnecessary HSTS header over HTTP
The HTTP page at [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) sends an HSTS header. This has no effect over HTTP, and should be removed.**

Now, I don't see it as a big problem but the pedantic nature inside me wants to fix it. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git) thread successfully resolving it but I want to ask how can I achieve this on my IIS. I am running an IIS on Windwos. Any help is reallly appreciated

[EDIT]
Some people misunderstood my question so sorry about that. What hstspreload website suggests is that you should only serve the HSTS header over https:// and that it useless to serve it on http:// requests. So my question is **"How do I only serve the header on https:// and not on http:// requests. I have implemented the HSTS header through IIS web.config. **

Comment: Administrative Tools > IIS Manager > Http Reaponse Header > Strict-Transport-Security > Edit Value : max-age=0;

Comment: To do this, it is easily possible in apache, but not sure with iis. +1

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10-version-1709/iis-10-version-1709-hsts

Answer (score -1):

It depend on how did you generate the HSTS header.

**Case 1:The header is generated by your application like asp.net core.**

Then you could just remove useHSTS from your application

**Case 2: The header is generated by IIS custom response header**

Please remove it from your web.config->httpprotocol/customheaders section.

**Case 3:  IIS 10 HSTS has been enabled.**

You could disable it from applicationhost.config->sites/site/HSTS. Set it to false.

URL rewrite can be used to add reponse header or rewrite its value. But it can't be used to remove the whole header.

Comment: hey Jokies, I think you misunderstood me. I don't want to remove HSTS. I just want to stop serving the header for http:// requests and only over https://